# Error sintaxis de codigo java-jsp

Tags: java, jsp

Estoy trabajando un jsp en el incluyo java, y he dado con un error mientras compilaba el código, es un error de sintaxis el cual no logro conseguir solventar, pues a pesar de poner las cosas que me pide, me sigue dando fallos y el programa pues no responde correctamente, algunas las he conseguido solucionar, pero otras no entiendo como poder llegar a arreglarlas, pues el eclipse me marca lineas absurdas que mi código pues no tiene, como aparece en esta imagen:

Editado: Si añado una llave al foro de cantidad de libros para cerrarlo, me da error posteriormente los elementoPedido, como se muestra a continuación en esta imagen.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Sin embargo, si esa misma llave la cierro justo despues entre la linea 111 y 112 con un <% } %>, desaparecen mis errores, pero luego me da un error http en la zona del for de mostrar cantidad de libros.

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ page session="true" import="java.util.*,es.Studium.Practica4DAW.*"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport"
    content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
<link rel="stylesheet"
    href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh"
    crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/estilo.css" type="text/css">
<title>Tu bolsa de la compra</title>
</head>
<body background="logo.png"
    style="background-repeat: repeat; background-position: 50% 5%">
    <div class="text-center bg-dark">
        <a><b class="text-info" style="font-size: 30px;">Tienda</b></a>

    </div>
    <div class="container mt-5 contenedores">
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <div class="col-4 col-12">
                <h1 class="text-light text-center">Bolsa de la Compra</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
        <form name="AgregarForm" action="tienda" method="POST">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-12 mt-4">
                    <div class="form-group row justify-content-center">
                        <div class="col-md-5">
                            <label for="inputUser" class="col-form-label text-light">Selecciona
                                un libro:</label> <input type="hidden" name="todo" value="add">
                            <select class="form-control" name="idLibro">
                                <%
                                // CARGA LIBROS PARA SELECCIONAR
                                for (int i = 0; i < LibrosTienda.tamano(); i++) {
                                    out.println("<option value='" + i + "'>");
                                    out.println(LibrosTienda.getTitulo(i) + " - " + LibrosTienda.getAutor(i) + " - " + LibrosTienda.getPrecio(i));
                                    out.println("</option>");
                                }
                                %>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group row justify-content-center">
                        <div class="col-md-5 col-mt-2">
                            <label for="inputUser" class=" col-form-label text-light">Cantidad:</label>
                            <input type="number" class="form-control" name="cantidad"
                                size="10" value="0">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="mx-auto mt-4 col-8 text-center">
                        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-info"
                            value="Añadir a la cesta"> <a href='./login.jsp'><button
                                type="button" class="btn btn-info">Salir</button></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <div class="col-2">
                <form action="tienda" method="POST">
                    <input type="hidden" name="todo" value="logout">
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
        <hr />
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <%
            // REVISA LO QUE HAY EN LA CESTA
            ArrayList<PedidoTienda> cesta = (ArrayList<PedidoTienda>) session.getAttribute("carrito");
            if (cesta != null && cesta.size() > 0) {

            }
            %>
            <div class="col-12 text-center">
                <p>
                <h3 class="text-light">Selección de Libros:</h3>
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <div class="col-12 mt-2">
                <table class="table table-striped text-light text-center" border="1">
                    <tr>
                        <th class="text-light">Título</th>
                        <th class="text-light">Autor</th>
                        <th class="text-light">Precio</th>
                        <th class="text-light">Cantidad</th>
                        <th class="text-light"></th>
                    </tr>
                    <%
                    // MUESTRA CANTIDAD DE LIBROS
                    for (int i = 0; i < cesta.size(); i++) {
                        PedidoTienda elementoPedido = cesta.get(i);
                    }
                    %>
                    <tr>
                        <form name="borrarForm" action="tienda" method="POST">
                            <input type="hidden" name="todo" value="remove"> <input
                                type="hidden" name="indiceElemento" value="<%=i%>">
                            <td><%=elementoPedido.getTitulo()%></td>
                            <td><%=elementoPedido.getAutor()%></td>
                            <td><%=elementoPedido.getPrecio()%> €</td>
                            <td><%=elementoPedido.getCantidad()%></td>
                            <td><input type="submit" class="btn btn-danger"
                                value="Eliminar"></td>
                        </form>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <div class="col-2">
                <form name="checkoutForm" action="tienda" method="POST">
                    <input type="hidden" name="todo" value="checkout"> <input
                        type="submit" class="btn btn-info" value="Finalizar Compra">
                    <br></br>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script
        src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script
        src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/acdf8e9705.js"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: El error es claro, te falta cerrar una llave `}`, y revisando tu código veo que nunca cierras el `for` que muestra la cantidad de libros. Ese es tu error.

Comment: Buenas, he actualizado la pregunta, he intentado cerrar la llave de dos formas, pero no me ha servido para solventar el error.

Comment: ¿Estás seguro que el `for` se cierra ahí? :)

Comment: Ya solventado el error, he reconstruido mi codigo de nuevo, muchas gracias por vuestra ayuda :)